# Getting a mongo collection array into a python dataframe using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, dataframe, pymongo

When using pymongo to export data from mongo into a dataframe in python i am having some trouble getting the data in the format i want

my data in  mongo looks as follows

```
db.data.findOne()
"_id": ObjectId("581b1b0d077ad53847d27340")
"index" : 0
"item" : {
       "bought" : 5.00
       "sold" : 7.49
}
```

then when I the following lines in python

```
pd.DataFrame(list(db.data.find()))
```

i get the following

```
id,                      index, item 
581b1b0d077ad53847d27340   0    {'bought' : '5.00',  'sold' : '7.49'}
```

whereas I would like the result to look like

```
id,                      index, item.bought, item.sold 
581b1b0d077ad53847d27340   0       5.00       7.49
```

any help on this matter would be greatly appreciated

Comment: `db.data.find()` return `json` ?

Comment: im not following, sorry

Comment: same idea as `MaxU` - use `json_normalize`.

Answer (score 3):

IIUC you can use [json_normalize()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.json.json_normalize.html) method:

```
In [78]: d = {
    ...: "_id": "581b1b0d077ad53847d27340",
    ...: "index" : 0,
    ...: "item" : {
    ...:        "bought": 5.00,
    ...:        "sold": 7.49}
    ...: }
    ...:

In [79]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(d)
Out[79]:
                        _id  index  item.bought  item.sold
0  581b1b0d077ad53847d27340      0          5.0       7.49
```

**UPDATE:** parsing multiple entries / rows:

```
In [162]: data = [
     ...: {"_id": "581b1b0d077ad53847d27340",
     ...:  "index" : 0,
     ...:  "item" : {
     ...:        "bought": 5.00,
     ...:        "sold": 7.49}
     ...: },
     ...: {"_id": "581b1b0d077ad53847d21111",
     ...:  "index" : 1,
     ...:  "item" : {
     ...:        "bought": 55.00,
     ...:        "sold": 99.99}
     ...: },
     ...: ]
     ...:

In [163]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
Out[163]:
                        _id  index  item.bought  item.sold
0  581b1b0d077ad53847d27340      0          5.0       7.49
1  581b1b0d077ad53847d21111      1         55.0      99.99
```

PS `data` is a list of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents one entry / row

**UPDATE2:** if MongoDB returns `item` as a string: `"{'bought':5.00,'sold':'7.49'}"` - we can preprocess the data in the following way:

```
In [168]: from ast import literal_eval

In [169]: data
Out[169]:
[{'_id': '0d', 'item': "{'bought':5.00,'sold':'7.49'}"},
 {'_id': '1e', 'item': "{'bought':55.00,'sold':'157.90'}"}]

In [171]: for i,x in enumerate(data):
     ...:     data[i]['item'] = literal_eval(x['item'])
     ...:

In [172]: data
Out[172]:
[{'_id': '0d', 'item': {'bought': 5.0, 'sold': '7.49'}},
 {'_id': '1e', 'item': {'bought': 55.0, 'sold': '157.90'}}]

In [173]: pd.io.json.json_normalize(data)
Out[173]:
  _id  item.bought item.sold
0  0d          5.0      7.49
1  1e         55.0    157.90
```

Explanation:

```
In [170]: [literal_eval(x['item']) for x in data]
Out[170]: [{'bought': 5.0, 'sold': '7.49'}, {'bought': 55.0, 'sold': '157.90'}]
```

Comment: This works wonderfully for one element at a time but is there a quick way to do it for an entire dataframe without using a for loop

Comment: The issue is that when i export from mongo the data inside the 'item' field has qoutes around it, so for youe example above it would be                                                                                                     ```data = [{"_id":"0d","item":"{'bought':5.00,'sold':'7.49'}"},{"_id":"1e", "item":"{'bought':55.00,'sold':'157.90'}"},] ```